# How to reboot car software in Renault Megane e-Tech EV? (2023)

Tags: renault, software, megane

I have an issue with the car software misbehaving (won't release charging cable) which I think could go away if I could restart the car's software.

Locking/unlocking the car doesn't reboot. Infotainment seems to be entirely separate — I can restart it or even reset to factory settings without the car's dashboard screen even reacting.

How can I reboot the software that controls the driving functions and/or the instrument cluster screen?

Answer (score 3):

It requires unplugging the 12V battery AND pulling out fuses under the hood (only fuses finally killed the computer and forced reboot, without 12V battery it it still ran off the inverter/main battery.)

BTW: there's no physical emergency cable release. Confirmed with Renault Assist. If the car does not stop charging and the reset doesn't help, you're SOL.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to take it back to the dealership for a warranty repair!